# how work with the returned array in ajax,json

Tags: java, php, jquery, ajax, json

i send some data to php ajax file, and there with if statement fill a array for response.
for example i have three array value. `$arr['number1']`, `$arr['number2']` , `$arr['number3']`.
but they not set together, some of them set and some another depend on condition may not set.
in jQuery side i want to show just set array values, what should i do?

i use

```
if(data.number1){
alert(data.number1)
}
if(data.number2){
alert(data.number1)
 }
 ...
```

but it doesn't work, because when the first line have a error java don't check the next line, what is the best way for this condition?
i want just show the keys that have a value

```
 $.post('inc/ajax/add_node.php',
                {some date},
                function(data){

                    if(data.number1){
                        alert(data.number1);
                    }
                    if(data.number2){
                        alert(data.number2);
                    }
                    if(data.number3){
                        alert(data.number3);
                    }
                },"json")
```

php code

```
$data=array();
if(){
  $data['number1']="val1";
  }elseif(){
   $data['number2']="val2";
   }

if(){
$data['number3']="val3";
 }
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: can you please add your ajax code with response you get ?

Answer (score 1):

You should echo all array with json_encode, and you can alert the response in object way.

instead you alert the response, You should print the return in console.log for the better view

Comment: i used alert just for testing

Comment: and set `header('Content-type : application/json');` for the output type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$.parseJSON` inside that function. Something like this:

```
function(data){
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
   if(data.number1){
         alert(data.number1);
   }
   ...
   //remaining part of code
 }
```